# Does a Facebook Live Video with status 'scheduled_live' mean that it is currently live?

Tags: facebook

According to [this page of the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/live_videos/) status can be:

`UNPUBLISHED, LIVE, LIVE_STOPPED, PROCESSING, VOD, SCHEDULED_UNPUBLISHED, SCHEDULED_LIVE, SCHEDULED_EXPIRED, SCHEDULED_CANCELED`

If I just want to know if a page is live streaming, and I'm checking the status of their `/<page_id>/live_videos`, is it enough to check for a status of `LIVE` or can it also be `SCHEDULED_LIVE`? Does `SCHEDULED_LIVE` mean that it is only scheduled or that it was pre-scheduled and is now currently live?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCHEDULED_LIVE as status means that the **video is scheduled** and **is not LIVE currently**.

As soon as the video starts, the status of even SCHEDULED_LIVE videos changes to LIVE.

So, yes it is sufficient to check status for 'LIVE' only to check if a video is live or not.

Comment: Thank you, I am marking this correct but if you can find any source for that it would be appreciated.

Comment: Actually I tested it myself and then posted the answer. I have been working on Facebook Live videos for last 1 year and have made a web-application using which users can post/schedule live videos to Facebook without using OBS or other 3rd party software. You can try www.shurikenlive.com

If you need any other information, let me know.